# Directory descriptor/finder gets stuck/crashes when trying to see if the input is indeed a directory

Tags: c, search, directory, path

I am coding in C, in a Mac. My code is supposed open a directory specified as an argument (or the current directory if no directory is specified as an argument), and it displays on the screen the name of all the entries of that directory, printing one entry per line. (I dont want to use fgets... etc).
When I press enter as an input (meaning no input), or I input an existing directory, the code works perfectly. But if i input an inexistent directory, then it gets stuck (returns nothing).

While debugging the code, it is strange as my "do while" condition is respected and gives no errors, but when the input is a non-existant directory, it just skips everything and doesnt even return anything (it should, in theory, skip the loop and raise the "perror" and return 1)
This is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "dirent.h"
const int PATH_MAX = 256;
void recursive_list(char *directory){
    DIR *dir = opendir(directory);
    if (opendir(directory) == NULL){
        perror("Cannot open directory");
        return;
    }
    struct dirent *ent;
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
    }

void myls(char *directory) {
    if (!directory) {
        perror("-1");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (!opendir(directory) ){
        perror("-1");
        return;
    }
        printf("%s\n", directory);
    recursive_list(directory);
        }

int main() {
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    char input[PATH_MAX];
    int i;
    if (!getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))) {
        perror("getcwd() error");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Directory:");
    fgets(input, PATH_MAX, stdin);

    if (input[0] == '\n') {
        myls(cwd);
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
            if (input[i] == '\n') {
                input[i] = '\0';
            }
        }

        do {
            if (chdir(input) == 0) { // If chdir to input succeeds
                getcwd(input, sizeof(input));
                myls(input);
                return 0;
            }
        } while (chdir("..") == 0);
            // If we reach here, it means all attempts to change directory failed
        perror("chdir() error");
        return 1;
        }
    }
```

Explanation of the code:
inside of main I gather the input and i proceed with the current path if nothing is given. If an input is given i "clean" it (eliminate \n) and proceed to the "do while loop". In the do while, I search for any possibility that it is a directory (i go to the parents in each iteration that doesnt find it). If everything fails (no more parents) it means there is no  such directory.

Inside myls I check once again if it is or not a directory (maybe It is redundant) and i print  that directory. Then I call recursive_list (might have to change that name)

In recursive_list I once again check if the directory exists and i go on printing all the elements inside the directory.

The main problem that would solve it (i think) is a way to detect if it is a non existant directory (which I tried in the do while loop).

I have tried many things and arrived to this code, but now i am out of ideas. I imagine there could be something done to search for the "brothers" meaning directories at the same level (all sons of a parent) and compare their names to the input? But that would mean high complexity I guess.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you open it twice? `DIR *dir = opendir(directory); if (opendir(directory) == NULL)` Make that 3 times since `myls` opens it too.

Comment: I believe `chdir("..") == 0` will always be true. So you will get stuck in that loop in case `chdir(input)` is failing.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding `chdir()` altogether.  It should not be necessary for your purposes, and it is usually counterproductive for a program to change its working directory.  Under some circumstances, doing so can be downright buggy.

Comment: Is this feature of searching for the specified directory in parent directories of the working directory actually required?  That's an unusual behavior (the regular `ls` command certainly does not do it) and it is not as well defined as you might think.

Comment: Ok, so ls command is for linux but is there any way to do such thing in c?
As for chdir(),If I dont use it, how could I get the directory from an input?@John Bollinger It interprets it as a char and wont get it as a directory. I also need to check for the parents if the input directory exists inside them. I will try to find a new condition in the while loop as EugeneSh. said it could be  an infinite loop.
I will try to avoid opening the directory twice too as Retired Ninja suggested. Thank you for your recommendations.